# Shopware 6 Administration: catch api error

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, shopware6

In my custom plugin i send a `write` request to server and the server response with an system (500) error:
`POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/my-entity 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The error is known and expected, it comes from the database because of duplicated entry:
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'my_entity.name'`

But how or where do i catch and handle the error on the server side to clean up the error message? [I have found this description](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-error-handling), but i'll handle the error *before* response to set the right http error.

Answer (score -1):

The [error handling seems to be a bug](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-26108)

For this specific use case, it is more appropriate to [use the `WriteCommandExceptionEvent`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Write/Validation/WriteCommandExceptionEvent.php) instead of the `PreWriteValidationEvent`:

```
// MyEntityValidationSubscriber.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1);

...

use MyPlugin\DAL\Exception\DuplicateEntryException;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\InsertCommand;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Validation\WriteCommandExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MyEntityValidationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            WriteCommandExceptionEvent::class => 'onWriteCommandException'
        ];
    }

    public function onWriteCommandException(WriteCommandExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        foreach($event->getCommands() as $command) {
            if($command->getEntityName() !== 'my_entity') {
                continue;
            }
            $haystack = $event->getException()->getMessage();
            $needleDuplication = "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry";
            $needleProperty = "key 'my_entity.name'";
            if(
                $command instanceof InsertCommand
                && strpos($haystack, $needleDuplication) !== false
                && strpos($haystack, $needleProperty) !== false
            ) {
                throw new DuplicateEntryException('violation.unique.myEntityName');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Excpetion class

```
// DuplicateEntryException.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1)

...

use Shopware\Core\Framework\ShopwareHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DuplicateEntryException extends ShopwareHttpException
{
    public function __construct(string $message, array $parameters = [], ?\Throwable $e = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    public function getErrorCode(): string
    {
        return 'DAL_DUPLICATE_ENTRY_EXCEPTION';
    }

    public function getStatusCode(): int
    {
        return Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    }
}
```